# Unable to build surround360_render - CMake issue

Tags: c++, linux, facebook, cmake, folly

**Background**
I am running this on Kubuntu 16.04.04 LTS, a fresh install.
I'm trying to build surround360_render based on the code and instructions at: https://github.com/facebook/Surround360/tree/master/surround360_render

- I followed the instructions except for the ones for the python, numpy, pip. gooey, pil installs (I don't need python).
- Installed ceres based on the instructions here, not the ones on the ceres git page.
- installed llvm, Halide to use accelerated ISP

and I get the following error while make'ing ...360_render:

```
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable bin/Unpacker
//usr/local/lib/libfolly.a(Conv.cpp.o): In function `folly::Expected<float, folly::ConversionCode> folly::detail::str_to_floating<float>(folly::Range<char const*>*)':
/home/rinka/bin/fb-lib/folly/folly/folly/Conv.cpp:354: undefined reference to `double_conversion::StringToDoubleConverter::StringToDouble(char const*, int, int*) const'
//usr/local/lib/libfolly.a(Conv.cpp.o): In function `folly::Expected<double, folly::ConversionCode> folly::detail::str_to_floating<double>(folly::Range<char const*>*)':
/home/rinka/bin/fb-lib/folly/folly/folly/Conv.cpp:354: undefined reference to `double_conversion::StringToDoubleConverter::StringToDouble(char const*, int, int*) const'
//usr/local/lib/libfolly.a(dynamic.cpp.o): In function `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToShortest(double, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const':
/usr/local/include/double-conversion/double-conversion.h:158: undefined reference to `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToShortestIeeeNumber(double, double_conversion::StringBuilder*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode) const'
//usr/local/lib/libfolly.a(dynamic.cpp.o): In function `std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<double>::value&&folly::IsSomeString<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::value, void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int)':
/home/rinka/bin/fb-lib/folly/folly/folly/Conv.h:704: undefined reference to `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToFixed(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const'
/home/rinka/bin/fb-lib/folly/folly/folly/Conv.h:708: undefined reference to `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToPrecision(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const'
//usr/local/lib/libfolly.a(Format.cpp.o): In function `folly::FormatValue<double, void>::formatHelper(folly::basic_fbstring<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, folly::fbstring_core<char> >&, int&, folly::FormatArg&) const':
/home/rinka/bin/fb-lib/folly/folly/folly/Format.cpp:162: undefined reference to `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToFixed(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const'
/home/rinka/bin/fb-lib/folly/folly/folly/Format.cpp:181: undefined reference to `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToExponential(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/TestRenderStereoPanorama.dir/build.make:112: recipe for target 'bin/TestRenderStereoPanorama' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/TestRenderStereoPanorama] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:556: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/TestRenderStereoPanorama.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestRenderStereoPanorama.dir/all] Error 2
[ 96%] Built target Unpacker
[ 96%] Built target GeometricCalibration
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

**What I've tried so far**

- I tried implementing https://github.com/facebook/Surround360/issues/253 Failed.  I get the following message:

  ```
  [ 98%] Generating folly_dep.cpp
  Scanning dependencies of target folly
  [ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/folly.dir/folly_dep.cpp.o
  [ 99%] Linking CXX shared library libfolly.so
  /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/ClockGettimeWrappers.cpp.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
  CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/ClockGettimeWrappers.cpp.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  CMakeFiles/folly.dir/build.make:514: recipe for target 'libfolly.so' failed
  make[2]: *** [libfolly.so] Error 1
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:180: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/folly.dir/all' failed
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/folly.dir/all] Error 2
  Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
  ```
- assuming it is a problem with the standard double-conversion-dev library installed by apt, I uninstalled that, recompiled double-conversion using the following instructions:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/google/double-conversion.git
  cd double-conversion
  cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
  make -j $(nproc)
  sudo make install
  ```
- and rebuilt folly as follows:

  ```
  $ cmake configure ..
  $ make -j $(nproc)
  ```

didn't work.  redid cmake & make

```
    $ cmake configure "-DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/bin/fb-lib/double-conversion/build/include" "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/fb-lib/double-conversion/build//lib" ..
    $ make -j $(nproc)
```

I get the following error:

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:201 (find_package):
        Could not find a package configuration file provided by "double-conversion"
        with any of the following names:

        double-conversionConfig.cmake
        double-conversion-config.cmake

    Add the installation prefix of "double-conversion" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
    set "double-conversion_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
    files.  If "double-conversion" provides a separate development package or
    SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Comment: ummm... OK. I fixed the issue.
I modified "CMakeLists.txt" in surround360_render.  I added "double-conversion" as an additional library to be linked and it works.

This was a defect that FB needs to take forward...

Answer (score 0):

The issues were because "double-conversion" was not included as a library to be linked in the various modules of surround360_render.  To solve the problem, modify CMakeLists.txt under the directory surround360_render as follows:

Add:

double-conversion

to the sections TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES of the various modules that fail.  In my case the failed modules were: TestRenderStereoPanorama, TestHyperPreview, TestPoleRemoval, TestColorCalibration, TestVignettingCalibration, TestVignettingDataAcquisition and GeometricCalibration

The reason I list these, there are more modules than these which is why one doesn't need to add double-conversion as a default library to be linked.

Putting this here in case someone else runs into similar issues.